# Secured XML feed import

Tags: php, xml, curl, import, xml-parsing

I am working on store products import from live XML feed.

Now I have one problem, with following code I imported several XML feeds, except this:

[XML Live Feed](https://services.it4profit.com/product/sl/712/PriceAvail.xml?USERNAME=tomicurk&PASSWORD=pocenipc1)

Code I used for all feeds is:

```
<?php
```

//dropshipper's feed URL
$myFeed = 'http://feedurl/feed.xml';

// specify the name of the file you want to save
$myFilename = 'some_feed.xml';

```
if ($myFeed != '') {
//  Initialize the cURL session
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myFeed);
//Create a new file
$fp = fopen($myFilename, 'w');
// Save to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
// Execute the cURL session
curl_exec ($ch);
//Close cURL session and file
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fp);

echo "Some Feed Imported Successfully!";


}
```

?>

But mentoined feed CAN NOT BE READ from script, and I dont know how to create import. This feed can be opened in browser and everyone can see data, but it can not be imported on server through script.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure it is a good idea to post your username (tomicurc) and password to your XML-Feed?
And secondly, have you tried file_get_contents? It works for me and is an easy way to get remote data which then can be stored.

Edit:

Try something like

```
if ($myFeed != '') {
    if($ch = curl_init()) {
        if(curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myFeed)) {
            if($fp = fopen($myFilename, 'w')) {
                if(curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp)) {
                    if(curl_exec ($ch)) {
                        curl_close ($ch);
                        fclose($fp);
                        echo "close completed, finishing";
                    } else {
                        echo "curl_exec failed";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "curl_setopt CURLOPT_FILE failed";
                }
            } else {
                echo "fopen failed";
            }
        } else {
            echo "curl_setopt CURLOPT_URL failed";
        }
    } else {
        echo "curl init failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Those username and pass will be changed, this is only demo xml feed. But I dont understand why this xml file can not be read with this code and every else can?! :)

Comment: Then try it the hard way: Check every operation for success or failure and see what happens. I've updated my previous response with a codeblock, try something like that. It is untested, but something along that line might give you a better idea of what is happening.
I still prefer file_get_contents ;-)